# WebAPI is not calling from WebService after hosting in IIS 8

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, iis-8

I need to send sms to a specific phone number through a WebAPI. So I have developed a webservice to call that WebAPI and hosted in IIS 8 (Windows 8.1) in my local pc. But problem is that when I run the webservice using Visual Studio 2015 (.NET Framework 4.5.2) and call the webservice, it calls the WebAPI and a sms send to a phone and in return WebAPI sends a xml data. But when I have hosted the webservice in IIS 8 in my PC, webservice cannot call the WebAPI, so sms could not be sent.

Code of Web Service and Error message are given below.

**Web Service**

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Send SMS (Param: =)")]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public string SendSmsParam(string url)
{
    try
    {
        string[] param = url.Split('=');
        string userName = param[0];
        string password = param[1];
        string fromMobileNo = param[2];
        string to = param[3];
        string message = param[4];
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpClient().GetAsync("https://abc.xyz.com.bd/ApacheGearWS/SendTextMessage?Username=" + userName + "&Password=" + password + "&From=" + fromMobileNo + "&To=" + to + "&Message=" + message).Result;
        return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Web Service Calling URL**:

`http://Localip:port/SendSMS.asmx/SendSmsParam?url=userName=password=fromMobileNo=to=message`

**Exception**

> " System.AggregateException: One or more
>   errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An
>   error occurred while sending the request. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved:
>   'abc.xyz.com.bd'    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult
>   ar)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean
>   waitCompletionNotification)    at
>   SMSWebService.SendSMS.SendSmsParam(String url)
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved:
>   'abc.xyz.com.bd'    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult
>   ar)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---<--- "

In office, network of my pc is configured through DNS and Proxy.

My question is why sms cannot be sent when webservice is hosted in IIS 8 where sms can be sent through webservice and WebAPI when webserivce is running using VS 2015 ?

One more thing is if I connect my pc to another network (not office network) suppose any other private ISP or any 3G/4G wireless network, I can send sms by calling the hosted Web Service. But as I already said that I can send sms by connecting my pc to my office network if i run the web service using visual studio. So where is the problem and how to resolve it?

Comment: `https://abc.xyz.com.bd` is that a valid domain?

Comment: @ramiramilu it is just an example

Comment: Then why are you running with example - `The remote name could not be resolved: 'abc.xyz.com.bd'`? Error clearly shows that you are using that domain.

Comment: @ramiramilu sorry, for some reason I cannot write the domain here. that's why i used 'abc.xyz.com.bd'. but domain which i am using is correct. bcz i already said that i can send sms if i run the web service using visual studio.

Comment: the request scheme is `HTTPS`. Are you sure no authentication is required while trying to access the resource?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh yes authentication is required from WebAPI end and that's why I am sending my username and password to WebAPI.